# Blowing up the projective space along a subvariety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I would like to know some global geometry of the blowup of projective spaces.

Question:  Let $Z\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ be a subvariety. How can I embed $BL_Z\mathbb{P}^n$ in a projective space or product of projective spaces?

Examples:

1. Let $Z\subseteq \mathbb{P}^4$ be a union of two disjoint lines, then $BL_Z\mathbb{P}^4\subseteq \mathbb{P}^2\times\mathbb{P}^2\times\mathbb{P}^1$, which is the blowup of $\mathbb{P}^2\times\mathbb{P}^2$ along a $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$.
2. Let $Z\subseteq \mathbb{P}^3$ be a twisted cubic curve, then $BL_Z\mathbb{P}^3\subseteq \mathbb{P}^3_Y\times \mathbb{P}^2_X$ is defined by
   $$X_0Y_0+X_1Y_1+X_2Y_2=X_0Y_1+X_1Y_2+X_2Y_3=0. $$

I don't know whether there is a standard way to obtain these constructions or not. Thanks very much for your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $I_Z$ be the ideal sheaf of $Z$. If the sheaf $I_Z(k)$ is globally generated (i.e., if hypersurfaces of degree $k$ cut out $Z$ as a scheme) and $m := h^0(I_Z(k)) - 1$, then
$$
\mathrm{Bl}_Z(\mathbb{P}^n) \subset \mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m.
$$

Comment: How can we write done the defining functions of $BL_Z \mathbb{P}^n$ in $\mathbb{P}^n\times\mathbb{P}^m$ using those degree $k$ polynomials cutting out $Z$?

Comment: This is tricky. Essentially, what you know from global generation is that there is an epimorphism of graded sheaves of algebras $$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}[t_0,t_1,\dots,t_k] \to \bigoplus I_Z^j,\tag{*}$$ hence a closed embedding of their projective spectra. To understand the equations you need to describe the kernel of $(*)$.

Answer (score 1):

(This answer is just here to explicitly spell out how Sasha's answer and the related comments work in the case of one of your examples.)

If you know a set of generators $f_1,\ldots,f_m$ for the ideal $I_Z(k)$, and a full set of relations holding between the $f_i$ (i.e. not just the syzygies (linear relations) but relations of higher degree too), then the blowup is the subvariety
$$ \operatorname{Bl}_Z\mathbb{P}^n \subset \mathbb P^n_{x_1,\ldots,x_n}\times \mathbb P^m_{f_1,\ldots, f_m}  $$
cut out by these relations. This is what is happening in your second example, since a twisted cubic $Z\subset \mathbb P^3_{Y_0,\ldots,Y_3}$ can be defined to be the vanishing locus of three quadratic equations
$$ f_0 := x_0x_2 - x_1^2, \quad f_1 := x_0x_3 - x_1x_2, \quad f_2 := x_1x_3 - x_2^2 $$
and any relation that holds between these equations is a consequence of the two syzygies
$$ x_0f_2 - x_1f_1 + x_2f_0 = 0, \qquad x_1f_2 - x_2f_1 + x_3f_0 = 0. $$
(In your notation $Y_i = x_i$ and $X_0,X_1,X_2 = f_2,{-f_1},f_0$.)

Comment: I am afraid this is a bit more subtle --- syzygies only measure linear (in my variable $t_i$) relations, but there could be also relations of higher degree.

Comment: Ah yes, I had overlooked that point. Thanks for the correction!